# Import/Export error: The requested module does not provide an export named 'pageFlip'

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

I recently switched over to the new Vite compiler for Laravel. I noticed that it somehow did not accept my window object anymore. No problem I thought, I'll just use imports/exports. However, I just keep getting the same error:

```
The requested module '../../../../../js/plugins/pageflip.js' does not provide an export named 'pageFlip'
```

I have searched all over the internet, but it keeps telling me not to confuse named exports/imports with default ones. However, I don't see anything wrong with my code. Could someone please help me with this?

show.blade.php

```
<div>
   HTML HERE
</div>

@push('scripts')
    <script type="module">
        import {pageFlip} from "../../../../../js/plugins/pageflip.js";

        @isset(condition here)
            pageFlip.turnToPage({{ $tale->taleUser->progress }})
        @endisset

        @can(condition here)
            pageFlip.on('flip', (e) => {
                document.getElementById('pageProgress').value = pageFlip.getCurrentPageIndex();
                document.getElementById('pageCount').innerHTML = pageFlip.getCurrentPageIndex();
            });
        @endcan

        function turnPage(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                return pageFlip.turnToNextPage();
            }

           return pageFlip.turnToPrevPage();
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

My script file:

```
import {PageFlip} from 'page-flip'

const pageFlip = new PageFlip(document.getElementById('book'),
{
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    size: ('stretch'),
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: 400,
    maxWidth: 1000,
    maxHeight: 1000,
    autoSize: true,
    disableFlipByClick: true,
    showCover: false
}
);

pageFlip.loadFromHTML(document.querySelectorAll('.tale-page'));

export { pageFlip }
```

The vite config file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel([
        'resources/css/app.css',
        'resources/js/app.js',
        'resources/js/plugins/pageflip.js',
    ]),
],
});
```

Judging by the error, I am a bit confused. I really am providing an export named 'pageFlip', right? Or am I possibly missing some vite configuration?

I am using the StPageFlip package provided by Nodlik.

Answer (score 0):

p should be capital in `PageFlip` in `show.blade.php` file. So replace `import {pageFlip} from "../../../../../js/plugins/pageflip.js";` with `import {PageFlip} from "../../../../../js/plugins/pageflip.js";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is not working unfortunately, I still get the same error.